# Connect Remotely to mysql running on a Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, localhost

I'm trying to connect MySQL Workbench to an Amazon EC2 (Linux) instance that hosts a MySQL Database. (Not RDS but localhost). However for some reason, I can't get it to connect remotely.

Things Ive done: 
- Set the security group to allow any IP to access port 3306
- Created a mysql user and granted all privledges on it.
- Modified the my.cnf to include bind-address=0.0.0.0 However i still cant connect.

On this instance I do have SSL cert installed and I am forwarded all http request to https?.. But im not sure if this has anything to do with it.

If anyone could guide my in the righ direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: Is IPTABLES on the instance blocking connections on port 3306? [This blog](http://www.iheavy.com/2014/01/28/connect-to-mysql-in-the-amazon-public-cloud/) has some useful tips on what to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally give it an Elastic IP so it will have a public IP, then bind the mysql to that IP. Make sure the iptables are set to accept the mysql connections. I also wouldnt suggest leaving mysql open to every ip unless this is an absolute necessity.